# Javascript IDE-style web app AJAX

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

I am impressed by ExtJS Samples/Demos especially the Border Layout examples. Is it feasible using ExtJS or other frameworks/libraries to build a viable web app that dynamically creates (say 10) new panels; something like how Eclipse builds and docks new split panels?.

These container panels would contain tabbed widgets and the panels would need to be maximizable/minimizable and closed completely if the last tab member is closed.
(again like how Eclipse closes it’s non-editor views).

I assume that CSS styles would have to be programatically added  to the DOM elements that make up the container panels but think that you could use style sheets for member layout(members could be document content or have their own widgets);

I suspect that performance would be poor and that there would be many problems in faithfully rendering the members style sheets.

I have no interest in writing an IDE in js but I am interested in knowing the limits of this approach for creating a ‘reasonably’ extensible app.

**I want to provide additional context to my question.**

Currently we have a desktop app in Java Swing which allows us create panels dynamically and has the features I outlined and works as follows.

Consider a simple Explorer  panel on the left and an Editor panel on the right.
Editing work can be for 4 different regions and all the work for a single region is grouped in tabs in the one panel. When the user is working on a region then other region editor panels are typically minimized; visually apparent as icons on a docking panel to the right of the Editor panel.

There is  total flexibility in letting the user switch working to a different region and in some cases even having 2 Editor panels open so that he/she can compare (and even do limited drag&drop from) work in one region to another. When 2 (or more) Editor panels are open they stack vertically under one another. There is no real need to have more than 2 editors open but it is allowed. We have logic that prevents mixing region views in the same editing container.
The current app performs well, allows multiple tabbed views  and permits users to segregate their work. More importantly it has allowed us to introduce and use different view ‘types’ providing the extensibilty I mentioned.

Before I get any responses saying that the design is wrong and that I should consider different layouts (*Accordion type panels on the left come to mind*) let me reiterate that I am interested in knowing the viability of this approach for a web app. whether or not we pursue this approach.

Trigger-happy dismissals of ‘subjective’ content are something I am willing to absorb.

Comment: so, are  you asking if it is possible to create 10 panels, or are you asking about limits in creating a 'reasonably extensible app'?  The latter of which is very subjective.

Comment: I'm pretty sure others must have tried something like this sometime and would appreciate any subjective or objective answers about their experience. ... or even why they rejected or would reject such an approach.

Answer (score 1):

That's an immensely broad question. Technically, I would say that the answer is yes, but your question suggests that you come from a world where the overwhelming paradigm is desktop applications. Trying to impose that dogma on a web context is possible, but suboptimal. You could probably do much better by embracing this media, which is radically different from the one you are familiar with. That is a tall order though.

Somewhere halfway in between, there are some gui toolkits that will allow you to build applications in a browser context, that in many respects act like traditional desktop applications. [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) might be of interest to you, since you use Java. Or, as you have found out your self, ExtJS also belongs in this end of the spectrum. You will have to learn a bit of Javascript, but the programming model is close to what you know from Swing.

Comment: Chuckle…….. I actually do program in JS and quite wantonly embrace the W** I mean the Web :).   But I am remiss in using loose terminology. Where I used web app I meant rich AJAX type applications which I carelessly assumed was clear from the context. I don’t mean RIA using Flash or Java or any other plugin.

BTW what is the proper terminology for  AJAX type apps that have just one page and use things like GWT, ExtJS or even Closure or Dojo. Notice I am concentrating on frameworks that use OO type development.